# Fiware To Payload too large

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I want to register data of approximately 3 MB by upserting it using ngsi-ld. It gives the following error. When I checked the Limitations document, it was set to 1 MB by default, but even when I changed it, I still encounter the same error. How can I resolve this?

```
{"type": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/errors/BadRequestData", "title": "Invalid Payload", "detail": "Payload too large"}
```

https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.0/user/known_limitations/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the document you are pointing at is referred to Orion, the NGSIv2 implementation, an not to OrionLD, the NGSI-LD implementation. The document version is also outdated (current Orion version is 3.11, in any case the inReqPayloadMaxSize continues as it was in 2.11).

Unfortunately I can not help you with NGSI-LD implemetation, maybe the configuration you are modifying is not avaliable in that service.

Best.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature implemented in both Orion and Orion-LD. I know that because I implemented it myself. Now, I took a look at the implementation of Orion-LD and I added a functional test (for some strange reason there wasn't one!), and I didn't really like the way it was implemented, especially the error handling.
So, I reimplemented it and added a functional test.
Please try again, with the newest image of Orion-LD in dockerhub (1.6.0-PRE-1573) and if you still have problems, just repost and we'll take a closer look at it.